# Extract Verbs from Sentence

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is a way to extract verbs from a string.

As an example :

> I'll eliminate you.

I want it to only extract "eliminate".

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this is homework you should show us what you've tried and we can give you help

Comment: Aren't there technically 2 verbs in that example?

Comment: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to be looking at using the Stanford PoS tagger (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml).  It will tag the string with it's classification (e.g. verb, noun).  You can then use a regular expression to pull out the verbs.

Comment: I downloaded tydevi (for Java) does it allow English verbs only ?
After I wrote my sentence , it kinda made a Diagram :x

Answer (score -2):

```
ArrayList<String> verbs = new ArrayList<>();
verbs.add("eliminate");

String yourtext = "I'll eliminate you";

for (String verb : verbs) {
    int index = yourtext.indexOf(verb);
    if (index >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Found verb: " + verb + " at position: " + index);
    }
}
```

I'll leave filling the verbs array up to you.

Comment: Ho... You want to help from a poorly specified problem and you see yourself retrograded. People are nice isn't ? ;)